# How do you define a static method collection in a generic struct

Tags: generics, rust

I am trying to use a collection of static method as generics inside a struct in order to change the behavior of a part of my code simply by changing the implementation of my trait.

My issue is that I am unable to use that generic if I do not include it in one of my traits despite the collection Having no data or method to speak of.

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

pub trait MyTrait {
    fn foo();

    fn bar();
}

struct MyStaticCollection {}

impl MyTrait for MyStaticCollection {
    fn foo() {
        println!("foo")
    }

    fn bar() {
        println!("bar")
    }
}

struct MyStruct<T: MyTrait> {
    my_data: String
}

impl<T> MyStruct<T>
    where T: MyTrait
{
    fn my_fonction() {
        T::foo();
        T::bar();
    }
}
```

this implementation returns the following error code :

> parameter `T` is never used consider removing `T`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `PhantomData`

isn't there a more elegant way than defining an empty field in `MyStruct` that instantiate an empty struct ?

the workaround:

```
struct MyStruct<T: MyTrait> {
    my_data: String,
    __: T
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with having a `PhantomData<T>` field?

Comment: Otherwise, you can put the generic on the method instead of the struct: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=f727107d79e4ee14d2338a63283e2120)

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler told you, you can use `PhantomData` marker for that purpose. This is a perfectly fine approach.

```rust
struct MyStruct<T: MyTrait> {
    my_data: String,
    phantom: PhantomData<T>
}
```

Citing [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html):

> Zero-sized type used to mark things that “act like” they own a T.
>
> Adding a `PhantomData<T>` field to your type tells the compiler that your type acts as though it stores a value of type `T`, even though it doesn’t really. This information is used when computing certain safety properties.
>
> For a more in-depth explanation of how to use `PhantomData<T>`, please see [the Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/phantom-data.html).